# Why does console.log() output an unexpected 0 in my code?

Tags: javascript, console.log

So here is my really simple code in JavaScript:

```js
var chessBoard = function (size) {
    for (var i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        var line = "";
        if (i%2 == 0)
            line =+ " ";
        for (var j = 0; j<size; j++) {
            if (j%2 == 0)
                line += " ";
            else
                line += "#";  
        }
        console.log(line);
    }
}
chessBoard(8);
```

Here is the output:

```
0 # # # #

 # # # #

0 # # # #

 # # # #

0 # # # #

 # # # #

0 # # # #

 # # # #
```

Why do I get those zeros in there instead of just empty strings. I am going to assume that it is something relative to the language but it is driving me nuts. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Because you do `line = +" ";` instead of `line += " ";`

Comment: Not really related, but you should make it pratice to use `===` instead of `==`, and parse separately if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
line =+ " ";
```

That should be `+=`. You're applying unary `+` to `" "` and running into Javascript's weird type coercion behavior.

Comment: Just VTC, it's a typo.

Comment: Specifically, that's explained in [9.3.1 ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1). Since the string is whitespace (*StrWhiteSpace*), then its mathematical value is 0. Then, it's rounded to `+0`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo where you write line =+ instead of +=.